# Is it possible for me to pass a prop from a child to a parent component on page load?

Tags: reactjs

How can i pass the hello const value which is in the ChildComponent to the App component and store it in the childProps variable of the App component on page load.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
  var childProps ''; // I want store the passed const value in this variable;
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const hello = 'Hope you are having a good day!';
    return <h1>{hello}</h1>;
  }
}
export default ChildComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass props from a child component to a parent component. However, we can always pass around functions from the parent to child component. The child component can then make use of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a callback to child component from parent component, it will be called once the child is mounted. Store that value in parent class property , if re-render requires maintain a state.

**App**

```
class App extends Component {

  helloCallback = (str) => {
    this.childProps = str
  }

  render() {
  
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent helloCallback={helloCallback}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  hello = 'Hope you are having a good day!'
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.helloCallback(this.hello)
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.hello}</h1>;
  }
}
```